# SQL Server keyword issue

Tags: sql

pls check the following line in SQL Server 2005 ---

```
create table School
(
   name varchar(50)
)
```

Why the "name" appears in BLUE color. As it is not a keyword.
Pls help me out.

Comment: Just change it to `[name]` and it won't be blue anymore.

Comment: It looks black to me. Seriously though, it's a (possible) bug in/feature of the syntax highlighter. Why worry about it?

Answer (score 2):

This is just how a particular tool (SQL Server Management Studio) highlights the word **name**. There's nothing so deep about this. It's in blue so it's in blue. It's probably because **name** is a *reserved word* even though it's not a *keyword*.

See also:

[SQL Reserved Words](https://www.drupal.org/node/141051)

In any case, seems **name** is a reserved word in some of the SQL dialects.

Answer (score -1):

Does the table create? If the table creates then it is appearing in blue to represent the data variable.

Also,  correct me if im wrong, but I do believe you need a ; after your ), but I did not test it in SQL Server 2005

```
create table School
(
   name varchar(50)
);
```

Comment: the table is created. no doubt. but just confused with the BLUE color of "name"

Comment: I would just ignore it, most SQL software will highlight variable names.